# Magento 2: Is there a dedicated folder for keeping PDF/image files for CMS pages and/or products?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, media, media-images, file

Since Magento 2 has [a default folder](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/data-import-product-images.html) for storing images to be imported at `[magento installation folder]/pub/media/import`, does Magento 2 also have a dedicated (or recommended) folder for storing PDF/image files (e.g. user guides, datasheet, product spec, marketing images not tied to any products nor theme, etc...)

Or would people just put these media files on whichever folder name they want? Would that affect dynamically generated SEO friendly URLs for categories, products, and CMS pages?

Comment: I always put import/export files under the var directory.

Comment: Wouldn't var directory be considered to be "removable" at any time? The folder I'm looking for is to stored media contents can be pulled from CMS pages or blocks. In the older version, I just made arbitrary folder and put those files into it, but I just want to double check if Magento 2 has a more preferred location to use.